# store data in asp.net with signalr

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr-hub

I am trying to store data in asp.net application with signalr. To ilustrate my problem here is example.

I have a hub that informs controll that user has connected and sends his id.

```
public static event EventHandler<IdEventArgs> userConnected;

public void Connected()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Hub Connected Method");
    var id = Context.ConnectionId;

    userConnected(this, new IdEventArgs(id));
}
```

Then I have my controller that adds event handler to hub

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        LoadingHub.userConnected += new EventHandler<IdEventArgs>(UserConnected);

        return View();
    }
```

And finally my method that should save the obtained data

```
    private void UserConnected(object sender, IdEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("User Connected with Id: " + e.Id);

        //To do:
        //save data
    }
```

I tryed saving to Session but Session object is null here. I came across user profiles and maybe this would be a good solution - is it possible to create new profile when user connects to store data inside, and when he disconects to destroy said profile? Or maybe completly diffrent approach is more siutable here?

Comment: What you's exact problem? what's your goal here?

Comment: I want to store data for a single user during connection

Comment: Then why don't you override hub's `onConnected` event ?

Comment: But stil I cant access session state to save/store that data

Comment: No access to the Session information through SignalR Hub.

Comment: Any other way is available to store that data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments, `Session` is not available with SignalR. I'd say you have 2 main options:

- use the *state* feature, as explained [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#passstate), this way your data will go back and forth over the connection but you'll have it around as long as the connection is alive (ideal for small payloads and if you don't mind clients accessing that info)
- use dependency injection (check [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/advanced/dependency-injection)) to pass a *service* to your hub, whose interface you define as you will (it could be a trivial pair of `get`/`set` methods), and whose implementations could be many, from an in-memory *static* (not necessarily literally) dictionary for dev scenarios up to any kind of persistent store you want to use to provide horizontal scalability (if needed). It's a bit of effort at the beginning but then it gets very easy and flexible

Answer (score 0):

I will give example for solution where you need to create Singleton service for holding connections for user. It is easy to modify to hold any type of data. Just need to inject it in required service, controller

```
public class ConnectionMapping<TConnectionKey>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<TConnectionKey, HashSet<string>> _connections =
        new Dictionary<TConnectionKey, HashSet<string>>();

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return _connections.Count;
        }
    }

    public void Add(TConnectionKey key, string connectionId)
    {
        lock (_connections)
        {
            HashSet<string> connections;
            if (!_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
            {
                connections = new HashSet<string>();
                _connections.Add(key, connections);
            }

            lock (connections)
            {
                connections.Add(connectionId);
            }
        }
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<string> GetConnections(TConnectionKey key)
    {
        HashSet<string> connections;
        if (_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
        {
            return new List<string>(connections);
        }

        return new List<string>();
    }

    public void Remove(TConnectionKey key, string connectionId)
    {
        lock (_connections)
        {
            HashSet<string> connections;
            if (!_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
            {
                return;
            }

            lock (connections)
            {
                connections.Remove(connectionId);

                if (connections.Count == 0)
                {
                    _connections.Remove(key);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public string ToJson()
    {
        var entries = _connections.Select(d =>
            string.Format("\"{0}\": [\"{1}\"]", d.Key, string.Join(",", d.Value)));
        return "{" + string.Join(",", entries) + "}";
    }
}
```